# Calendar.SelectedDate response.write in Years, days and hours

Tags: c#, calendar

What I basicly want is to convert a Calender..SelectedDate
To an age is Years, Days and Hours - In a `Response.Wirte()`.

If your bithday is : `19-09-1995 (DD/MM/YYYY)`
it will `Response.Write`

```
Age: 18 years 
Days: 18*365+3 = 6573 
Days Hours: 6573 * 24 = 157752
```

But it also has to work on another date this year so If the birthday was yesterday

Comment: Why Response.Write() ?  Just use a label or literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this code assumes that there is no such things as leap years in the world :)

```
private string GetAnswer()
{
    DateTime birthday = calBirthDate.SelectedDate;
    TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Date - birthday;
    int leapYears = CountLeapYears(birthday);

    int days = (int)difference.TotalDays - leapYears;
    int hours = (int)difference.TotalHours - leapYears * 24;

    int years = days / 365;

    String answer = String.Format("Age: {0} years", years);
    answer += Environment.NewLine;
    answer += String.Format("Days: {0}*365+{1} = {2}", years, days - years * 365, days);
    answer += Environment.NewLine;
    answer += String.Format("Days Hours: {0}*24 = {1}", hours / 24, hours);
    return answer;
}

private int CountLeapYears(DateTime startDate)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int year = startDate.Year; year <= DateTime.Now.Year; year++)
    {
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
        {
            DateTime february29 = new DateTime(year, 2, 29);
            if (february29 >= startDate && february29 <= DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I got 2 errors :
Error 1 } expected D:\School\ASP\H Klas\Master Pages\Master Pages 1.0\KalenderLeeftijd.aspx.cs 15 6 D:\...\Master Pages 1.0\

and:

Error 2 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected D:\School\ASP\H Klas\Master Pages\Master Pages 1.0\KalenderLeeftijd.aspx.cs 54 1 D:\...\Master Pages 1.0\

Comment: And it's not writing the answer back on my page, like Response.Write("");

Comment: My code is working, so please check that you have copied it all. May be you fogot some brackets. Now you have method, that returns string. You can write this string whereveryou want

Comment: so basicly just Response.Write("count"); will doe the job? - sorry im new to this -

Comment: String answer = GetAnswer(); Response.Write(answer);

Answer (score 0):

```
        string date = "19-09-1995";
        DateTime birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Date - birthday;

        int years = (int)difference.TotalDays / 365;
        int days = (int)difference.TotalDays;
        int hours = (int)difference.TotalHours;
        String answer = String.Format("Age: {0} years", years);
        answer += Environment.NewLine;
        answer += String.Format("Days: {0}*365+{1} = {2}", years, days - years * 365, days);
        answer += Environment.NewLine;
        answer += String.Format("Days Hours: {0}*24 = {1}", hours / 24, hours);
```

But this info is not true, because it does't count leap years

Comment: Leapyears don't matter :)
What I need is :
calBirthDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GebDatum);
So basicly getting the date of birth out of the calendar named "calBirthDate" and then turning it into 
as DateOfBirth is :19-09-1995 (DD/MM/YYYY) 
You will get: 
Age: 18 years 
Days: 18*365 = 6570 
Days Hours: 6573 * 24 = 157680
p.s: these answers are WITHOUT leap yeears

Comment: You can write DateTime birthday = calBirthDate.SelectedDate; and use my code. Or is something wrong?